# Sklearn Decision Tree Classifier showing float error Python [not a duplicate]

Tags: python, sklearn-pandas

I want to make a program for prediction using `sklearn DecisionTreeClassifier.`

Im comparing two lists, `ListOnePar` that has float values, and `timelist` that has only strings. I always get the same error. I searched the web and I didnt find anything that can help me. All I saw that comparison can be done between two lists (one with floats and other with strings.)
This is not a duplicate of the other question, in the other question the error is totally different, and the whole program is different.

**This is the error :**

```
Pred1=tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'DecisionTreeClassifier'
```

**This is the code :**

```
from sklearn import tree

    ListOnePar=[]

    for child in tree1.get_children(id1):
        ListTwoPar=[]

        one=round(float(tree1.item(child,"values")[1]),2)
        two=round(float(tree1.item(child,"values")[2]),2)
        tree=round(float(tree1.item(child,"values")[3]),2)
        four=round(float(tree1.item(child,"values")[5]),1)
        five=round(float(tree1.item(child,"values")[6]),1)

        ListTwoPar.append(one)
        ListTwoPar.append(two)
        ListTwoPar.append(tree)
        ListTwoPar.append(four)
        ListTwoPar.append(five)

        ListOnePar.append(ListTwoPar)

    timelist=[]

    for child in tree1.get_children(id1):
        time=tree1.item(child,"values")[7]
        timelist.append(time)

    Pred1=tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
    Pred1=Pred1.fit(ListOnePar,time)

    size=float(PredSizeEntry.get())
    time=float(PredTimeEntry.get())
    cost=float(PredCostEntry.get())
    level=float(PredLevelEntry.get())
    subcontractors=float(PredSubcontractorsEntry.get())

    ListForPrediction1=[]
    ListForPrediction2=[]

    ListForPrediction2.insert(0,size)
    ListForPrediction2.insert(1,time)
    ListForPrediction2.insert(2,cost)
    ListForPrediction2.insert(3,level)
    ListForPrediction2.insert(4,subcontractors)

    ListForPrediction1.append(ListForPrediction2)

    prediction1=Pred1.predict(ListForPrediction1) 
    print(prediction1[0])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can't use scikit-learn - "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743889/cant-use-scikit-learn-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute)

Comment: Thats the complete code for prediction.
I have made the similar code that works perfectly , only difference it that I that code, I entered lists values manually , and in this code I did it by using for loop.
With for loop, i get values from tree view, and all values in tree view are float, except values in list time, those values are string.

Comment: just check if you have multiple versions of `sklearn` installed. That might be causing the issue.

Comment: I do not have multiple versions of (sklearn) installed, i have just checked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- I think there is a variable in your program `tree`
- The program is confused to use import statement `tree` or `tree` variable because you are overwriting the `tree` to float
- Change the variable name to `three`

  ```
  for child in tree1.get_children(id1):
      ListTwoPar=[]

      one=round(float(tree1.item(child,"values")[1]),2)
      two=round(float(tree1.item(child,"values")[2]),2)
      tree=round(float(tree1.item(child,"values")[3]),2)   # <===== variable to be changed from tree to three
      four=round(float(tree1.item(child,"values")[5]),1)
      five=round(float(tree1.item(child,"values")[6]),1)
  ```
- You are making `tree` as float while calculating the `tree=round(float(tree1.item(child,"values")[3]),2)` hence you are getting the error : `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'DecisionTreeClassifier'`

Comment: tree1 is the name of treeview, I can not change that. I use that to get the values for tree view.

Comment: `tree=round(float(tree1.item(child,"values")[3]),2) ` You have typo in this line. You wrote tree instead of three

Comment: ooooh.. yes...Ill check that

Comment: change `tree=round(float(tree1.item(child,"values")[3]),2)` to `three=round(float(tree1.item(child,"values")[3]),2)`

Comment: Well I think that I you helped me fix that problem, but now I get this error when I run the program:

`TypeError: Singleton array array('nene', dtype='<U4') cannot be considered a valid collection. `

Comment: Can you please mark the solution correct for your current question... Do you have any function in your program... `TypeError: Singleton array array('nene', dtype='<U4') cannot be considered a valid collection` occurs when you have the variable name as same as that of a function