# module 'sklearn.preprocessing' has no attribute 'Normalization'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I try to to use the `preprocessing` method from sklearn. I found other threads with the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743889/cant-use-scikit-learn-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute) but it didn't helped me to uninstall my existing sklearn versions. I think my problem is still that I have somewhere on my mac a scikit package. I just wonder how to fix this error?

My imports:

```
!pip install -q git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as p
```

My code where the error line is dropped:

`normalizer = preprocessing.Normalization(axis=-1)`

Error:

`AttributeError: module 'sklearn.preprocessing' has no attribute 'Normalization'`

Comment: Do you mean `preprocessing.Normalizer`?

Comment: Also, I doubt `Normalizer` have `axis` parameter

Comment: Well in that case it's just `preprocessing.normalize(axis=-1)`

Comment: Look in documentation [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression#the_normalization_layer) there its `normalizer = preprocessing.Normalization(axis=-1)`

Comment: So based on the doc link you provided, the class you're trying to use isn't from scikit-learn.  Try `from tf.keras.layers import Normalization`.

Comment: Good idea but its not working in this way. - Same Error. @Frodnar